# Assets in the public directory not showing in Laravel 5

Tags: php, css, laravel, assets

I am having issues with assets in the */public* directory in Laravel 5.4 and Laravel 5.5.

On a fresh install of Laravel, nothing in the public directory will work without */public* in the URL.

When I run `php artisan make:auth`, the views that are created are supposed to be perfect, right? Well, what I get is an unstyled page which only looks pretty when I use the DOM inspector to add */public* so that I end up with:

```
<link href="http://localhost/l5.4/public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Where can I change the setting so that I don't have to add */public* in the views each time I want to link to an asset?

Comment: Did you check for the permissions for that directory? Ensure you have given proper permissions. Check this article which may help you : [Securely setting file permissions for Laravel Framework](http://vijayasankar.me.pn/blog/2017/02/04/securely-setting-file-permissions-for-laravel-framework/) also you need to set DocumentRoot [Check Step 4](http://vijayasankar.me.pn/blog/2017/01/17/installing-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-aws-ec2/)

Comment: Permissions seem to be fine. The step 4 you linked to seems to make a lot of sense. I don't need to edit anything though. I can just just go to `http://localhost/l5.4/public/`  when I want to visit the website. I just did that and it works fine. The issue is that I need a solution that will not give me headaches when I deploy the site. I need something that won't force me to fiddle with cPanel. Is there a way of telling the helper function `asset()` to append `public/` to the paths?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do that manually there is a function shipped with laravel: `{{asset('css/app.css')}}` this access directly the public folder.

**Note:**

If that doesn't work then you're high probably need to set up a virtualHost that points on you `/public` folder.
You can do that in your vHosts file on Apache.

**Note2:**

If you're on a shared hosting per example, or you can't modify your vHost file for a reason or an other, here is the solution you've got.

First, you have to put your public folder above the project folder and rename it per example public_folder, inside it, you'll have to put the content of the public folder.

```
/public_folder
/your_project_folder
  app/
  databases/
  ...
```

Second, inside the public folder you will find a file called `index.php` you have to modify it as follows:

```
require __DIR__.'/../your_project_folder/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../your_project_folder/bootstrap/app.php';
```

That means you're referencing the project folder from the public folder we created above.

**Note3:**

To tell laravel that the asset function going to be referenced from the new location of our public folder, you can add this to your index.php, after `$app=require_once...` :

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: `{{asset('css/app.css')}}` would still not work as it creates:  `<link href="http://localhost/l5.4/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">` and not `<link href="http://localhost/l5.4/public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">` which is what works. 
Is creating a vHost something I can easily do in cPanel? I doubt

Comment: If you can't set it up via cpanel you can do this (in shared hosting per example) check the edited answer

Comment: u basically need to tell laravel to reference the public folder from the location of the public folder: `$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});`

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:
To `url` in `config\app.php` I entered the full URL to the `public` directory like this:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/l5.5/public'),
```

I also entered the same URL to `APP_URL` in the `.env` file because that is what I'm using for configuration.
Apparently `asset()` and similar functions append to the URL in the configuration file when constructing the file URL

**UPDATE:**
The problem with doing it this way is that I'm now having to edit `Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php` which I believe is a bad idea. I believe core files should not be touched. 
Now instead of

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
}
```

I am using

```
function asset($path)
{
    return config('app.url'). '/' .$path;
}
```

May someone tell me the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In root folder rename **server.php** to **index.php** and copy **.htaccess** file from public folder to root folder. Also share your directory structure to show where your assets are places.

Comment: I always do this. Even when I do that the assets still need `/public` to be accessed

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: That's obviously how anyone would do it. If not, the views made by the `make:auth` command would obviously have that. I think what I need now is a way to tell the `asset()` method to add `public/` to the paths of assets. It would not be a good solution but a working fix

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This works just fine. When Laravel runs on the server the main index file and all assets are in the “public directory”. So the css asset files would start with domain name + css/file.css not domain/public/css/file.css.