# Laravel API return link to image

Tags: json, laravel, api

for my laravel api, i return in json an object containing a title and a link to an image.

but in laravel I do not know in which folder and how to return the full link of the image that will be displayed on mobile application.

the data is saved on a mysql database

example:

```
{
   "title" : "example",
   "image" : "http://www.example.com/images/example.png"
}
```

Thanks for your help

------------- UPDATE ------------

I add a route to test :

```
Route::get('v1/pictures/{filename}',function($filename){
    return asset('/storage/app/public/images/'.$filename);
});
```

when I call : http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pictures/chat1.jpg
I get : http://localhost:8000/storage/app/public/images/chat1.jpg

but when I go to this link I have a not found error : Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: could you elaborate more? any example of issues?

Comment: what is the link of the image if it is in the folder: /storage/app/public/images/example.png ? and how can I get this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo asset('/storage/app/public/images/example.png');
```

this should echo something like

```
yourpage.com/storage/bla/bla/example.png
```

Comment: I have one image in : /storage/app/public/images.chat1.png and if I go to  : http://localhost:8000/storage/app/public/images/chat1.png I get an error page not found, I need to configure something ?

Comment: it does not help me, I still can not get my image in my browser

Comment: is this file really there? take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-storage-path

Comment: I just edit my post, if you see any other possibility I'll take it :)

Comment: have you tried `asset('storage/something')` without `/` in front? also it may be htaccess issue, check this topic and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050332/assets-in-the-public-directory-not-showing-in-laravel-5